Why does the genfit function in mathcad work strangely?
I have a tabular function of two vectors x and y
x y
-5.00000000000000e+000  9.08419036515801e+000
-4.86884290294375e+000  9.18474413956781e+000
-4.86842653120706e+000  9.28030145313736e+000
-4.80263979681059e+000  9.37835699712704e+000
-4.73685306241412e+000  9.47641254111671e+000
-4.67106632801765e+000  9.57446808510638e+000
-4.60527959362119e+000  9.67252362909606e+000
-4.53949285922472e+000  9.77057917308573e+000
-4.47370612482825e+000  9.86863471707541e+000
-4.40750301869509e+000  1.00622475746346e+001
-4.34171628429862e+000  1.01603031186243e+001
-4.34129991256194e+000  1.02558604321939e+001
-4.27551317816547e+000  1.03539159761835e+001
-4.20972644376900e+000  1.04519715201732e+001
-4.07856934671275e+000  1.05525252945830e+001
-4.01278261231628e+000  1.06505808385727e+001
-3.94699587791981e+000  1.07486363825624e+001
-3.81583878086356e+000  1.08491901569721e+001
-3.81542240912687e+000  1.09447474705417e+001
-3.74963567473040e+000  1.10428030145314e+001
-3.61847857767415e+000  1.11433567889412e+001
-3.55269184327768e+000  1.12414123329308e+001
-3.48690510888121e+000  1.13394678769205e+001
-3.42153474622143e+000  1.13419661073406e+001
-3.35574801182496e+000  1.14400216513303e+001
-3.22459091476871e+000  1.15405754257401e+001
-3.15880418037224e+000  1.16386309697298e+001
-3.02806345505267e+000  1.16436274305700e+001
-2.96269309239289e+000  1.16461256609901e+001
-2.83153599533664e+000  1.17466794353999e+001
-2.76616563267685e+000  1.17491776658200e+001
-2.63542490735729e+000  1.17541741266603e+001
-2.50468418203772e+000  1.17591705875005e+001
-2.43931381937794e+000  1.17616688179206e+001
-2.30857309405838e+000  1.17666652787609e+001
-2.17824874047550e+000  1.16761044260316e+001
-2.04792438689262e+000  1.15855435733022e+001
-1.98255402423283e+000  1.15880418037224e+001
-1.85222967064996e+000  1.14974809509930e+001
-1.78727567972686e+000  1.14044218678436e+001
-1.65695132614398e+000  1.13138610151143e+001
-1.59158096348420e+000  1.13163592455344e+001
-1.52662697256110e+000  1.12233001623850e+001
-1.39630261897822e+000  1.11327393096557e+001
-1.20102427447225e+000  1.09491193737769e+001
-1.13607028354915e+000  1.08560602906275e+001
-1.07111629262606e+000  1.07630012074780e+001
-9.40791939043178e-001  1.06724403547487e+001
-8.75837948120082e-001  1.05793812715993e+001
-8.10467585460299e-001  1.05818795020194e+001
-6.80143231877421e-001  1.04913186492901e+001
-6.15189240954324e-001  1.03982595661407e+001
-5.49818878294541e-001  1.04007577965608e+001
-4.84864887371445e-001  1.03076987134113e+001
-2.89170171128784e-001  1.02196360911021e+001
-1.58845817545905e-001  1.01290752383728e+001
-2.81050922263395e-002  1.01340716992131e+001
3.76816421701296e-002   1.02321272432027e+001
1.68422367489694e-001   1.02371237040430e+001
2.34209101886163e-001   1.03351792480326e+001
3.65366198942416e-001   1.04357330224424e+001
4.30736561602199e-001   1.04382312528626e+001
5.61893658658450e-001   1.05387850272723e+001
6.27264021318234e-001   1.05412832576925e+001
7.58421118374485e-001   1.06418370321023e+001
8.24207852770954e-001   1.07398925760919e+001
8.89578215430737e-001   1.07423908065121e+001
1.02115168422367e+000   1.09385018944914e+001
1.08652204688346e+000   1.09410001249115e+001
1.21767914393971e+000   1.10415538993213e+001
1.28346587833618e+000   1.11396094433110e+001
1.41462297539243e+000   1.12401632177208e+001
1.54578007244868e+000   1.13407169921306e+001
1.61156680684515e+000   1.14387725361202e+001
1.67693716950493e+000   1.14412707665404e+001
1.80809426656119e+000   1.15418245409502e+001
1.87388100095765e+000   1.16398800849398e+001
1.93925136361744e+000   1.16423783153600e+001
2.00503809801391e+000   1.17404338593496e+001
2.07082483241038e+000   1.18384894033393e+001
2.20156555772994e+000   1.18434858641795e+001
2.39809301744598e+000   1.19465378690095e+001
2.52841737102885e+000   1.18559770162801e+001
2.72452845900820e+000   1.18634717075405e+001
2.78948244993130e+000   1.17704126243911e+001
2.98517716617396e+000   1.16823500020819e+001
3.11591789149353e+000   1.16873464629221e+001
3.18087188241662e+000   1.15942873797727e+001
3.31119623599950e+000   1.15037265270433e+001
3.37615022692260e+000   1.14106674438939e+001
3.50647458050548e+000   1.13201065911646e+001
3.57142857142857e+000   1.12270475080152e+001
3.70175292501145e+000   1.11364866552858e+001
3.76670691593455e+000   1.10434275721364e+001
3.83124453512096e+000   1.08548111754174e+001
3.96156888870383e+000   1.07642503226881e+001
4.09189324228671e+000   1.06736894699588e+001
4.15643086147312e+000   1.04850730732398e+001
4.28633884331932e+000   1.02989549069409e+001
4.35129283424241e+000   1.02058958237915e+001
4.41624682516551e+000   1.01128367406420e+001
4.48078444435192e+000   9.92422034392306e+000
4.54573843527501e+000   9.83116126077362e+000
4.61027605446142e+000   9.64254486405463e+000
4.67523004538452e+000   9.54948578090519e+000
4.73976766457093e+000   9.36086938418620e+000
4.80472165549403e+000   9.26781030103677e+000
4.93462963734022e+000   9.08169213473789e+000

Next, I'm trying to approximate the function

with three parameters a0, a1, a2. I attached a screenshot of the code below

Here G(z,a) is a function and its derivatives for each parameter a0, a1, a2. Vector g initial values of parameters a0, a1, a2. Vector a is the resulting parameter values after applying the genfit function.
When I try to plot, the resulting graph does not fit on the points.


The function you have chosen cannot adequately represent those data with the two peaks either side of zero. The best that my fitting code can do with that equation and those data is a gull wing shape that is about 7 when x = 0 and cuts through the two maxima tapering off to about 13 at infinity (L2 norm fitting, L1 norm was worse).

I can take a0 = 1.5 , a1 = 0.003, a2 = 10. The graph fits fairly well on points with such parameters.

I can get an almost acceptable fit if I take a0 = 1.05375, a1 = 0.000138, a2 = 118.9 and change the value of "2" in the denominator to 1.341 (ie make it a free parameter in the fit). The behaviour near zero is still not right though. It is sensitive to starting guess.

And yet, why doesn't genfit output the correct parameter values?

There is more than one local optimal set of fitted parameters and the wrong one is much easier to find than the better global optimum. You have to start pretty close to the true solution with a good guess before it converges properly to the solution that you want. Otherwise you end up on some variant of a gull wing shape with a minimum at ~7.  Double check the position of the first terms brackets (a0^2exp(-8a1*x^2)-1) - the solution is even more wrong if the bracket is on the wrong side of a0^2.
